# How find endpoints of my heroku deployed nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Below you can see my localhost nodejs api endpoint and its successfullyworking.

http://localhost:3000/api/user/login/
[image]

But after I deployed app in Heroku I cannot call that endpoint.
[image]

After deployed in the heroku I tried with this url

```
https://employee-management-app-001.herokuapp.com/api/user/login
```

Below you can see my server file

```
   const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const uri = 'mongodb+srv://user1:1234@cluster0.pkiw6x0.mongodb.net/comp3123_assignment1'
    //const jwt =require('jsonwebtoken');
    var cors = require('cors')
    app.use(cors())
    mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database mongoDB Atlas Server");    
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Could not connect to the database.', err);
        process.exit();
    });
    
    app.use(express.json())
    const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')
    app.use('/api/user',usersRouter)
    
    const employeesRouter = require('./routes/employees')
    app.use('/api/emp',employeesRouter)
    
    mongoose.connect(uri)
    app.listen(port,()=> console.log("Server Started on Port "+port))
```

Can anyone helop me to solve thiss issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You aren't showing your `usersRouter` file so we can't know how that works, but you're including a trailing `/` in the first example and not in the second.

Comment: If that's not the issue, Heroku wouldn't change your routes. Are you entirely sure that you deployed the same code you're running locally?